# Android 3 elements in row, with the last aligned Right

Tags: android

How i can do this: [image]

I use `match_parent` for `Title`, but it takes off from the screen the 2nd image.

Comment: can you show the layout which you have used for this

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Comment: use relative layout. with that you can achieve this  view. you can adjust views to left or to right of other views

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBook"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBookName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBook"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Book Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please just don't copy paste any irrelevant code from any where. only include the things which are required to address the OPs question

Answer (score 0):

User `Weight` for this type of layout.
or you can made this layout using `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"  />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `0dp` width textviews without any weight wont be visible to the user

Answer (score 0):

The better way is using of `android:layout_weight` in a LinearLayout with a horizontal(default) orientation.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3" >

<-- use your own designed backgrounds-->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"/>

 <-- use your own designed backgrounds-->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Something" />

<-- use your own designed backgrounds-->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can adjust both weightSum and weight by the requirment design.